# UX Flow after user sign in Single Page Application

Tags: ux-designer

I've built a single page application using angular(MEAN) and curious to know the how the user navigation needs to follow after he has logged in. A guest can see several sections in the single page (home.htm) and navigate across the sections simply by scrolling.

However when a user signs in, I want to show details pertaining to user such as profile, orders etc on the nav bar. But if the user wants to checkout information like About Us when he is logged in do I navigate him out of his current page to the home page and then provide a link to bring him back. I'm little confused on how to integrate the login flow in a single page application

Comment: A side question here: shouldn't you have thought about that before actually building your application? I mean your question most certainly belongs to the design phase which is the very first phase of the development pipeline of a product.

Comment: @rbaleksandar some people design and develop at the same time (especially in the lean world).

Comment: At a later point changes in design should come only if development comes across something that cannot be properly implemented (or for some other reason). Designers do the intensive work at the beginning and then move forward to another project (but are still partially available for feedback from the devs). It really depends on the project, the dev team, the design team, the company that makes and the company that buys the product. Still here we are talking about some very basic things that are not supposed to be in a state "Hm, I wonder if the users will ..." at this stage.

Answer (score 1):

It's two completely separate sections of the site. It isn't especially dependent on being a SPA.

WordPress is a good example.

1. Either you are logged in to the admin area and can do all the admin type things like editing/creating a page/post/users
2. Or you are viewing the site and can view/navigate the pages

Once you're logged in WordPress provide a menu bar at the top to allow switching between the admin / site.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Most of the newer informational sites are opting for one page design.

Since these are usually only informational sites and do not have actions to be performed, login is not necessarily required.

But for your requirement, I would think a good way to do it would be to have the entire site as one page, and direct the user to the main landing page after login. Give him a menu, or a one button option to view/edit his profile. [This will also be the place, where he has the option to logout]

Since it is a single page application, the about-us and all other sections have to be on the same page. So either the user scrolls to that section mannually. Or he has a navigation bar that allows him to skip diretly to that section.

Comment: your suggestion of having entire site as one page is how the current design is in my Single Page Application with just 1 .htm file but multiple sections in it. Let me know if thats what you meant. The way I'd thought of designing this is, to provide user option to login in navbar. But post login,I'll take the user to his profile page which is shown in just one section and the remaining sections are not shown(with help of angular router). But if user wants to see 'about us' details from this page, I'll provide him link in a universal footer section to take him there. He can be back using navbar

Comment: Hey Raj, why would you have the link in the footer section? Even with your one page design, you would have some sort of navigation (on the top or the left?), and if yes, then why not add the "about us" link in that nav bar

Comment: Adding the about us to the nav makes it too crowded when a user is signed in. It however makes sense when no user is logged in. I want to seggregate the information that I need to show to a logged in user from a normal user

Answer (score 0):

Once a user has logged in they should remain within the logged in session. I would think that jumping from 'secure' and 'unsecured' sections of the site I am assuming that the user will have a visual cue that they remain within a secured session?

Adding the logged in options to the navigation should help, and these should remain while the user is logged in. If they move to the about us section the logged in options should still be there[image: guest state]This is the normal non logged in state

[image]
Once logged in.